# Vanishing second derivative at a point, but non-vanishing first derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Is it possible for a real $C^2$ function $f:U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ with $U$ an open set, to have a point $p \in U$ such that the second partial derivative $f_{11}(p) = 0$ but $f_1(p) \neq 0$? In the case of one dimension, this would translate to $f''(p) = 0$ but $f'(p) \neq 0.$

I believe this to be true, but I cannot come about proving by the definition of the second derivative; I believe that taking the limit as the increment goes to zero should make me conclude that we are forced to have $f'(x) = 0,$ but I am not certain of this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: start playing around with polynomials (and if you read the logic of Taylor polynomials backwards you should easily see why this is obvious). If you only make assumptions on derivatives at one point, you can’t really constrain the behavior of functions in any way.

Comment: I thought about the inflection point of $f(x) = x^3$, but there we also have that the first derivative vanishes,

Comment: I would say you should try harder, but the reality is you should try simpler. In fact as I alluded above, something much more is true: given any numbers $a_0,\dots, a_n$, i can find a $C^{\infty}$ function (actually a polynomial) such that for all $1\leq k\leq n$, $f^{(k)}(p)=a_k$. I can even do this for an infinite sequence (then of course we no longer get polynomials…this is a special case of *Borel’s lemma*).